# UnavailableShardsException in elastic search cluster configuration

Tags: cluster-computing, elasticsearch

I have tried an elastic search cluster configuration with 3 nodes in Amazon EC2. But I am getting UnavailableShardsException after the call `$type->addDocument($doc);`

The following are the configuration on each of the 3 nodes in the custer. Please help !

```
Node1
=====
cluster.name: MyCluster
node.name: node1
node.master: true
node.data: true
# index.number_of_shards: 5 //Not confugured this, to use the default value 5
index.number_of_replicas: 2
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200

Node2
=====
cluster.name: MyCluster
node.name: node2
node.master: false
node.data: true
# index.number_of_shards: 5 //Not confugured this, to use the default value 5
index.number_of_replicas: 2
transport.tcp.port: 9301
http.port: 9201

Node3
=====
cluster.name: MyCluster
node.name: node3
node.master: false
node.data: true
# index.number_of_shards: 5 //Not confugured this, to use the default value 5
index.number_of_replicas: 2
transport.tcp.port: 9302
http.port: 9202
```

Comment: Are you running all 3 nodes on the same EC2 instance?

Comment: No, 3 different EC2 instances of identical configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EC2 doesn't support multicast, so for a cluster to function, you need to use either [unicast](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/discovery/zen/) or [EC2 discovery plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/discovery/ec2/). I would suggest starting with unicast since it's typically much easier to setup. Since all 3 nodes are running on different instances, they can all be configured with the same ports (9300 and 9200). If you still have issues with making it work uncomment the following line in logging.yml, restart all three servers and post a link to log files from all 3 servers here.

```
  #discovery: TRACE
```